# Is it possible to distinguish between a subset of an array?

Tags: typescript

Sorry for the bad title, I didn't know how to explain it better in one sentence.

I'll just paste the code I have so far, because I believe it should be quite self-explanatory.

```
// I have a columns const that never changes
const columns = ["a", "b", "c"] as const

// I have editable columns, that is a subset of columns,
// which also never changes, so I make it readonly.
type EditableColumns = readonly (typeof columns[number])[]

// In this case, a and b are editable, c is not.
const editableColumns: EditableColumns = ["a", "b"] as const

type Props<T> = { data: readonly T[], editableColumns: EditableColumns }

// Now what I'm trying to accomplish here...
// is that I want any of the editable columns to get some extra info,
// and I want all of the other columns to NOT get that extra info.
type Foo<U, T extends Props<U> = Props<U>> = {
  [key in typeof columns[number]]: key extends T["editableColumns"][number]
    ? {
        readonly column: key
        readonly row: U
        readonly extraInfo: "HELLO"
      }
  : {
      readonly column: key
      readonly row: U
    }
}

let foo = {} as Foo<string>

// But right now, as you can see,
// ALL the columns get the extra info.
// Even though I didn't want foo.c to get the extra info.
// You can see that when you mouseover foo.c
foo.a
foo.b
foo.c

// How do I make sure that a and b are included and c is excluded?
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEElQCwQwNwKahqAxgewDYFcC2A7AZzXSIBdQzYL8FEAnNWfAcwUICgNyScDiAvKADaAIhiiANKFEAjKTNSiAusmLdCZDhxARo8JAgAmASzIxZmJBj5FpVGBRPEUhbLMIIK6AGa88djpgAO5QJqhQyJiE6KC0DEwwrOzSMXq4MADWSGag9AgwRqSYAJ4AdBxkJQAOSACipuaWCADCWAGCeQVF+KWgABRVtb7+-ML4eLII9MoAlMLK2rrg+JRh6jCe0ihJRqCyyPmgxmYWVtKooM5x6GQVGhQnTVZttoQAXKANp82vHaBCMQSaRyFRqEjkbRDJAABXo6GqhAAPAAVAB8ANAAG9QEZHDBPvlCsUSqAUQtpE8zq12vxPt9njS3qAAL5LMAAOXQwVAoUcEAA5LhKPQSiZWJRYjBUBhcNVMM5IlBpggymqgldiA4KJBgkkKElSSMqIZGtTRkRJaA2BQYrhDAAPMj0FDinzoSQa3Z6PX4A2YTCgY3KoMmxg2f5kWIcgDyKOtXjW-IQTpdV3w7oq0NAADF0OgkQBVaTxlNkBD4IzEOEI5GFjFCGuIotohvYjigETZUniyg1BAjCNjCa4KYzZSfbvHJ0VqtksRU360ogqcaTaaLTudgD87a3+66xN6pKH+EnCBKHYPnaJPT68OCn0LV+vt5J0+dMBW7s+ogAEnUAAygExqIL5bmynafFi4E3t076nuel6vvBx55NyT7gWybIcFYFDurEQhYiy4J5gWmj0OKLBouyoAAELYBQlEsFANDctsxAlOg2BoEkoCeAgnq6AAgsBazWMuxA2uJH5pm66AVLodSIKsVDcSxeimEY+AChQvr4fmZSXFGCYUCasmuhmCkagAmtxvGrAJSZ6cqqxcTxuDcZ46AJARRkcH5MABYZsjBQpqC0X+3K4rEkAZNk-HYEc2rIMglb7IcOT4KgOBGMYaV7Jc1wpjl2B5UY24cEAA)

Comment: I'm confused about why you're doing so much here; my attempt to pare it down and get the minimal viable solution looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5eLZN).  Your `EditableColumns` type is always going to have all three keys so there's no way for the compiler to get the information about which keys are actually editable unless you tell it directly (or compute it `const editableColumns = ["a", "b"] as const; type EditableColumns = typeof editableColumns[number]`, but that's more code than necessary to get this behavior). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Your `const editableColumns` is not referenced anywhere in your `Foo` type definition. If you change it as follows, `foo.c` will be restricted as per your requirements:

```
const columns = ["a", "b", "c"] as const;

type EditableColumns = readonly (typeof columns[number])[];

const editableColumns = ["a", "b"] as const;

type Props<T> = { data: readonly T[], editableColumns: EditableColumns };

type Foo<U> = {
  [key in typeof columns[number]]: key extends (typeof editableColumns)[number]
    ? {
        readonly column: key
        readonly row: U
        readonly extraInfo: "HELLO"
      }
  : {
      readonly column: key
      readonly row: U
    }
};

let foo = {} as Foo<string>;
foo.a;
foo.b;
foo.c;
```

Not very clear what you're actually trying to achieve though.